# Compute an ANOVA with transformed variables

Tags: r, anova

I have a dataframe `df`

```
df<-structure(list(Y = c(1.20167297867875, 1.27851224829923, 1.18763208884216, 
1.23765309504143, 1.30246129512516, 1.19258132417647, 1.17015215455443, 
1.16756342150402, -0.000206480999730317, 0.292683228844456), 
    P = c(1750.51986303926, 1614.11541634798, 951.847023338079, 
    1119.3682884872, 1112.38984390156, 1270.65773075982, 1234.72262170166, 
    1338.46096616983, 458.433428257704, 1198.95775346458), TA = c(9.10006221322572, 
    7.65505467142961, 8.21480062559674, 8.09251754304318, 8.466220758789, 
    8.48094407814006, 8.77304120569444, 8.31727518543397, 10.4412463804413, 
    8.14410265791868), A = c(49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 
    0, 1)), .Names = c("Y", "P", "TA", "A"), row.names = 2803:2812, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to make an ANOVA almost in the same way as I already did.

```
lm1 <- lm(y~ P + TA + A, data=df)
Anova<-aov(lm1)
summary(Anova)
```

The difference is that now I want to transform one of my variables (`A`) according to the function below

```
f1<- function(x) {0.384394*(x^0.341429)*(exp(-0.004749 *x))}
```

Where the function means that  variable y= 0.384394*(A^0.341429)*(exp(-0.004749 *A).

My linear model would be something like

```
lm2<-lm(y~P+TA+ my transform A, data=df)
```

Does someone know how to perform that?

Comment: As noted by @ccurtis below, you've already done this. Though, I would suggest that there's no reason to write a function for that transformation. Just `df$A2 <- 0.384394*(df$A^0.341429)*(exp(-0.004749 * df$A))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically did all the work already. Just modifiy column A with your function and re-run your anova.

```
df2=df
df2$A<-f1(df$A)
df2
lm2 <- lm(Y~ P + TA + A, data=df)
Anova2<-aov(lm2)
summary(Anova2)
```

Comment: But by doing that I am replacing my values A by a transformation of my values Y, right? Because my function is: Y= 0.384394*(A^0.341429)*(exp(-0.004749 *$A). Somehow I need the inverse of this function to have A as a function of Y.

Comment: Or can I say in my linear model that P +TA~Y and P~f1(Y)?

Comment: Sounds like a math problem. Try Wolfram alpha. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%3D0.384394*%28A%5E0.341429%29*%28exp%28-0.004749+*A%29%29+for+A

Comment: Thanks. It does not give A=f(Y) though.